# Kube modal closes when pressing enter in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a modal from the [Kube CSS & JS framework](https://imperavi.com/kube/docs) (6.5.2) with a form inside it. When I hit enter, the modal closes without submitting the form.

**Edit**: this doesn't happen when focused on password or search inputs - changing the type from 'text' to 'password' fixes the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Kube CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/kube.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div id='ui-modal-test' class='modal-box hide'>
        <div class='modal' style='width:95%'>
            <span class='close'></span>
            <div class='modal-header'>Modal Form Test</div>
            <div class='modal-body'>
                <form id="ui-modal-form">
                    <input type="text" name="field1">
                    <input type="text" name="field2">
                    <input type="text" name="field3">
                    <button>Apply</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button data-component="modal" data-target="#ui-modal-test">Open</button>

    <!-- Kube JS + jQuery are used for some functionality, but are not required for the basic setup -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/kube.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$('#ui-modal-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // modal still closes before submitting form

    var field1 = $(this).find('input[name=field1]').val().toLowerCase();
    var field2 = $(this).find('input[name=field2]').val();
    var field3 = $(this).find('input[name=field3]').val();

    $.post('/post.php', {
        field1: field1,
        field2: field2,
        field3: field3,
    }, function(response){
        var response = JSON.parse(response);

    });
});
```

I'd like the form to submit when the user hits enter on any of the inputs, without closing the modal box.

Comment: I duplicated the same thing on my computer and seems to be working just fine. I'm able to submit and see the response from the backend. I can submit when the cursor is on any of the fields.

Comment: Strange, I've tested this in Chrome, FF and IE. All the same... Are you submitting using enter?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both with mouse and with enter

Comment: Well something must be different. What version of Kube and jQuery are you using? I've just downloaded the latest versions and have the same problems.

Comment: I've done it without Kube, just jquery to see if the submission is happening or not

Comment: Ah! well my question concerns Kube. It works for me without the modal obviously.

Comment: Why are you listening for a `submit` event in a div?

Comment: Just a mistake! I've edited the post now. Surprised no one else noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no idea about Kube, but I tried what you said, that was an issue. Then I opened the kube.js file in dist folder to check out the modal.
I found this specific function to be the cause at line number 2167 -

```
handleEnter: function(e)
    {
        if (e.which === 13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.close(false);
        }
    }
```

13 is the code for Enter key event. It's by default in kube, I guess. Maybe you can override this, I think there are some functions in it to disable events. If I change the parameter like this `this.close(true)`, it works well.

Hope this gives you the cause of why this is happening.

Kube seems nice :)

Comment: In line 703, you can see the definition of the close function. By passing false, it skips the first check to prevent default behavior. Passing true thus solves the issue in this case.
That's one way I found to solve it, there may be some other.

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function` on line 2004 but at least the modal doesn't close!!

Comment: Nevermind, removing the whole function fixes the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
            <form onSubmit={event => event.preventDefault()}>
                <input type="text" name="field1">
                <input type="text" name="field2">
                <input type="text" name="field3">
                <button>Apply</button>
            </form>
```

you can also refer if still not work:

submit isn't required, so in your case I would recommended moving your logic over to beforeSubmit and always return false as this is triggered before the modal closes. Currently, there's no way to manually close the modal, other than triggering the event modal:destroy. This is an example:

```
var Modal = Backbone.Modal.extend({
  template: _.template($('#modal-template').html()),
  submitEl: 'button',
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    // show your awesome loader here
    this.model.save(this.model.attributes, success: function() {
      this.trigger('modal:destroy');
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Your modal doesn't submit if it doesn't succeed and beforeSubmit is only triggered onEnter and onClick of the button.

Comment: Note quite working, there's an error on `this.model.save(this.model.attributes, success: function() {`. `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Where'd you get this code from? Looks like something from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Same behaviour as before. I've updated my question to show how it's submitted.